# Django rest framework multi searching

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

everyone. I tried understand search.
I have url  `path('quiz/all/', QuizListView.as_view()),`
View :

```
class QuizListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Quiz.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizDetailSerializer
    search_fields = ('description', 'title',)
    filterset_fields = ['title', 'description',]
```

(method1)If I use search, for example `/api/v1/quiz/all/?search=Q`I got all instances where title or description contains 'Q'
(method2)I can search `/api/v1/quiz/all/?title=Q&description=d` I got a instance which has exact title and description.

(method3)But I want to get list of all instances where title contains one value and description contains other value. For example, I want to write `/api/v1/quiz/all/?title=Q&description=d` and get list where title contains Q and description contains d.

- Quiz1(title=Q, description=d)
  Quiz2(title=Test, description=dd)
  Quiz3(title=NewQ, description=Test_d)
- For (method1,/api/v1/quiz/all/?search=Q) I got Quiz1, Quiz2, Quiz3
- For (method2,/api/v1/quiz/all/?title=Q&description=d) I got Quiz1
- For (method3,/api/v1/quiz/all/?title=Q&description=d) I would like to
  get Quiz1   and Quiz3 (because they contain `Q` for title and `d` for description)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom `FilterSet` class and use the `contains` or `icontains` (if you want case insensitive) because the default is using `exact` and that's why you don't get back the result that you want. See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exact)

```
# filters.py

class QuizFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = {
            'title': ['contains'],  # or icontains
            'description': ['contains'],  # or icontains
        }
```

```
# views.py
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from .filters import QuizFilter

class QuizListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Quiz.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizDetailSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )  # add here other filters backends
    filterset_class = QuizFilter
```

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot!